# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_io' pip install don't work

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I try to train my model, but when I run this command to do it:

```
$ python3 Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config
```

I get error like so:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_io'
```

I try to install it with 'pip' but I get another one

```
$ pip install tensorflow.io
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow.io (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow.io
```

I also try to fix it with GitHub issue https://github.com/tensorflow/io/issues/1298 and it work for me. I follow the last comment there and I get

```
Successfully installed tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.21.0
```

and I try it in python3 in terminal:

```
>>> import tensorflow.io
>>>
```

So why when I try to train my model it fails ?

Im using MacBook Pro with M1, and I have no idea how to fix it.
Thanks for any help

Comment: It's `tensorflow-io`, not `tensorflow.io` for pip, and `tensorflow_io` for the module name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pip install tensorflow_io instead of pip install tensorflow.io